# How do I get Cucumber Extent Reports to work with Cucumber 5.6.0?

Tags: java, cucumber, cucumber-java, extentreports

I went from Cucumber 1.2.5 to Cucumber 5.6.0. The upgrade went quite smoothly, however my Extent Reports broke. I attempted to upgrade them and use the [Cucumber 4 Adapter](https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber4-adapter). The documentation was sparse, and I could not get it to work. So I went and downloaded the [Example Implementation](https://github.com/foursyth/extentreports-cucumberN-example). I was able to compile and run it and get reports. I upgraded the example project to Cucumber 4.8.1, and the Extent Reporter to 4, and it ran, but no report was created. I'm at a loss and my google searches have turned up no info.

Here is the original example project: https://github.com/foursyth/extentreports-cucumberN-example

Here is my attempt to update it: https://github.com/dougnoel/extentreports-cucumberN-example/tree/update_to_Cucumber4-adapter

This is the pom.xml:

```
    <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <cucumber.version>4.8.1</cucumber.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
        <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-core</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-junit</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

This is the test runner:

```
package cucumber.examples.java.calculator;

import org.junit.runner.RunWith;

import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:", "json:target/cucumber-report.json"}
, tags = { "@foo" }
)
public class RunCukesTest {

}
```

Here is the project I updated to Cucumber 5.6.0 and in which I am trying to keep Extent Reports working: https://github.com/dougnoel/sentinel/tree/93_update_cucumber

Comment: U could have a look at this - https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-cucumber5-adapter

Comment: @Grasshopper that looks like what I want. Thank you.

Comment: Checkout boilerplate code: https://github.com/nitinsmartsense/smartsense-cucumber-testng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answered by Grasshopper in a comment. The solution was the [fantastic instructions](https://grasshopper.tech/1697/) and [code](https://github.com/grasshopper7/cuke5-extent-adapter-report) that he provided.

In the pom.xml I added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>4.1.5</version>
</dependency>

<dependency>
    <groupId>tech.grasshopper</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber5-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.1.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In my test runner I put:

```
package cucumber.examples.java.calculator;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import io.cucumber.junit.CucumberOptions;
import io.cucumber.junit.Cucumber;

@RunWith(Cucumber.class)
@CucumberOptions(monochrome = true
    , features = "src/test/java/features"
    , glue = { "stepdefinitions", "com.dougnoel.sentinel.steps" }
    , plugin = {"com.aventstack.extentreports.cucumber.adapter.ExtentCucumberAdapter:"}
```

The final piece was adding a configuration file `extent.properties` in `src/test/resources/` with just three lines:

```
extent.reporter.html.start=true
extent.reporter.html.out=reports/extent-cucumber-report.html
screenshot.dir=reports/
```

It now all works as it did before!